# Nvidia driver with secure boot password enabled and no display at all

Tags: nvidia, uefi, display

I recently installed the Nvidia drivers on Ubuntu 18.04, there was an option to enable secure boot with UEFI; I set up a password and after installing the driver, I restarted the desktop. Now, there is no display at all, I cannot access any startup options and I cannot live boot with USB also. Is there any fix to solve this issue?

Comment: I suggest you try with Secure Boot disabled. If it works that means the Nvidia drivers weren't properly signed.

Comment: I can't even access BIOS

Comment: You must so, find a way. Usually pressing ESC repeatedly right after powering on does that. Or check your user's manual for other ways.

Comment: Hi @nyxkryptor, did you find a solution to this?

Comment: I would not say a solution, but I was able to access BIOS somehow and disabled secured boot and did a fresh install of Ubuntu.